# Статические экземпляры классов в Flask

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, static

К примеру, есть код:

```py
from flask import Flask

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "1"

    def change(self):
        self.var = "2"


foo = Foo()
foo.change()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    return foo.var


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Как в данном случае будет работать инициализация и изменение экземпляра класса `Foo`? Это произойдёт один раз при запуске сервера? Или это будет происходить при каждом обращении к серверу? Где про это можно почитать?

---

И если это происходит при каждом обращении, то можно ли как-то зафиксировать статический экземпляр инициализированного и изменённого экземпляра класса `Foo` для всей сессии работы сервера?

Comment: 1) Перед запуском сервера 2) Обращение к серверу будет через функцию `def test():` 3) Добавьте print'ы и смотрите что выводится

Comment: @gil9red Да, спасибо. Не додумался сам проверить с помощью `datetime`. Оформите как ответ? Или мне самому себе ответить, как я с помощью времени это проверил?

Comment: Оформите самостоятельно ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно было это самостоятельно проверить с помощью отметок времени.

```py
from flask import Flask
from datetime import datetime


class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var = "None"

    def change(self):
        self.var = str(datetime.now()) # Устанавливаем время, когда был вызван метод


foo = Foo()
foo.change()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/test", methods=["GET"])
def test():
    return "In class: " + foo.var + "<br>Current datetime: " + str(datetime.now())


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

При обновлении страницы видно, что значение, взятое из экземпляра класса, не меняется.